# Search in Wordpress - Difference of searchpage.php, searchform.php and search.php?

Tags: search

I'm sorry for this scholar question, but I'm totaly confused with search in Wordpress. What is the difference beetwen `searchpage.php`, `searchform.php` and `search.php`? Could anybody tell me how it all works? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is most likely referring to a specific theme, but I'll answer it for the current default Twenty Ten (Wordpress Theme) as it's well documented. You find it in the `wp-content/themes/twentyten` directory.

The main search template in there is `search.php`. It is the template file to display the search page. Which means either only the search form or when called for a search, the search results as well.

`searchform.php` is a *template part*, so a fragment to hold the search form. The default theme does not ship with it by default, but if it exists it will load it instead of a hardcoded search form. Here is the default search from:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
<div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">' . __('Search for:') . '</label>
<input type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" />
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'. esc_attr__('Search') .'" />
</div>
</form>'
```

That is done in the wordpress function `get_search_form()` which is part of the core package and used by many themes including Twenty Ten.

`searchpage.php` is something specific to another theme I guess, as it is not used within the default theme and worpdress core. I assume by name, that it's having the same or a similar meaning as `search.php` but being specific to some other theme.

Comment: `searchpage.php` has [an article in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page) and you can find some [tutorials on creating it](http://www.jtpratt.com/wordpress-hack-3-custom-search-results-page-and-template/), but indeed, it seems to be a complete search form with hints, like [the one on this site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search). Maybe in earlier versions of WP `search.php` was only used to display results and not as a "search start page" when no query was entered?

Comment: Thanks, I realized it. It's just for the specific themes.

Answer (score 0):

searchpage.php is a custom page that usually includes searchform.php.
It offers functionality for the end-user to enter search criteria and press submit button.
The results appear in search.php.